# Can't catch the exception - Java with HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, htmlunit

I don't understand what's going on ???

I have the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    WebClient wc = null;
    HtmlPage hp = null;
    ArrayList<Product> allProducts;
    try{
        wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        hp = wc.getPage("http://www.mega.co.il/");
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }
    finally{
        allProducts = getProducts(wc, hp);
        for (Product product : allProducts) {
            System.out.println(product);
        }
    }
}
```

and still the console shows an javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException being thrown in the 
hp = wc.getPage("http://www.mega.co.il/"); line :

```
    Aug 3, 2011 10:45:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrame loadInnerPageIfPossible
SEVERE: IOException when getting content for iframe: url=[http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/logins/rightLoginHPIframe.jsf]
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:597)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:133)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1459)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1324)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:303)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrame.loadInnerPageIfPossible(BaseFrame.java:141)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrame.loadInnerPage(BaseFrame.java:100)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadFrames(HtmlPage.java:1763)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:204)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:436)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:369)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:354)
    at DBSniffer.main(DBSniffer.java:107)
```

can someone explain me what's going on?

P.S
Somehow the application proceed to run !?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: Looks like the exception was caught internally. If you print something in your catch statement, do you see it?

Comment: no it never goes to the catch statment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception printed is never propagated to your catch clause. It is caught internally, and printed on standard error.

To suppress the warnings you need to tell the API not to print them.

Try the following:

```
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Comment: but if it's caught internally, why does eclipse tells me that i need either to catch this exception or to throw it further. this means no one catches it in the process !?

Comment: Exactly which exceptions does it say you need to catch?

Comment: I'm sorry you are right no need to catch this exception, Thanks

Comment: but the above doesn't help, i still get the stack printed, do you know  maybe how to avoid the exception form happening?

Comment: It sounds like the exception isn't stopping your test, so you can ignore it?   Otherwise, this might help:  http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html